Get rid of "Rvnc connect" window
I have a Pi I use as a kiosk, with VNC enabled on it. It's running RaspberryPi OS, minimal setup, with X installed.
At startup, for a brief moment, you can see a "Rvnc connect" window, that displays the machine IP address and some other information (I don't know what exactly, it's too fast, I videod it, but still too fast and is blurry).
I'd like to get rid of that window (hide it "forever", prevent it from even opening...).
